# Specified location path on NGINX not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-emr

I have an AWS EMR and I have been trying to configure a path **(/hbase)** to access HBase in EMR through NGINX. To achieve my goal I have created a configuration file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/hbase.conf`.

```
 server {
 charset utf-8;
 listen  80;

 #Hbase works when location /hbase/ is replaced with location /.
 It does not work like below.
 location /hbase/
 {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:16010;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }
}
```

Here is my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`on EMR

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  include       /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;


# HTTPS server
server {
    listen 18888 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/nginx.key;

    server_name localhost;

    location /webhdfs/v1/user {
      proxy_pass    http://localhost:14000;
      proxy_read_timeout 1800;
      proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
    }

    location /sessions {
      proxy_pass    http://localhost:8998;
      proxy_read_timeout 1800;
      proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
    }

    location /batches {
      proxy_pass    http://localhost:8998;
      proxy_read_timeout 1800;
      proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
    }
    location /proxy {
      proxy_pass    http://ip-10-100-0-4.ec2.internal:20888;
      proxy_read_timeout 1800;
      proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
    }
  } #end server tag
} #end http tag
```

The problem is when I hit the `http://tempmyserverurl/hbase` it gives me **404 Not Found** error. But when I update the location **/hbase** to **/** in my `hbase.conf` it redirects to `master_status` and HBase UI is accessable.

[image: Not found error]

[image: Working hbase.conf]

[image: Working HBase UI]

I simply want NGINX to load HBase with `location /hbase`. I have tried using a different server and mentioned proxy pass to this EMR server but it did not work.

Can anyone help me put in the right direction? Help me figure out what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this url https://www.liaohuqiu.net/posts/nginx-proxy-pass/

Comment: try to change `proxy_pass http://localhost:16010` to `proxy_pass http://localhost:16010/hbase`

Comment: @Lamanus. I tried changing proxy_pass http://localhost:16010 to proxy_pass http://localhost:16010/hbase.  It gave the same HTTP 404 Error (Problem accessing /hbase). I hit http://example.com/hbase in the browser and received 404. Thanks for the resposne.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
location /hbase
{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:16010;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

A request to `http://example.com/hbase/some/path` would be `proxied` to `http://localhost:16010` like `http://localhost:16010/hbase/some/path` which most likely does not exist because the `hbase` is in the URL thus the 404 error.

From https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

> If the URI is specified along with the address, it replaces the part of the request URI that matches the location parameter.

```
location /hbase
{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:16010/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

With this example, a request to `http://example.com/hbase/some/path` would be `proxied` to `http://localhost:16010` like `http://localhost:16010/some/path` thus removing the `hbase` from the URL which most likely fixes the issue.

Comment: I tried 
`  location /hbase/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:16010/;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
`
When I hit `http://example.com/hbase` the request is redirected to `http://example.com/master-status` and I still receive `404 Not Found Error` When I place `/hbase/` in the URI like `http://example.com/hbase/master-status` by typing in address bar I get the desired result (HBase UI is available). I think this means I need to place `/hbase` somehow in the proxy pass I already tried @Lamanus suggestion but it did not work.